# Error using Stanford CoreNLP in command line

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am new to working with programs written in Java and am having a whole lot of trouble getting StanfordCoreNLP to do what it's supposed to do. I unzipped the program into its own directory, to which I added the XML file the program is supposed to process. The code I've been using to process the file in command line is:

java -cp stanford-corenlp-YYYY-MM-DD.jar:stanford-corenlp-YYYY-MM-DD-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP [ -props  ] -file .

The problem is that every time I try to run this I get the following error: "could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP." I'm just not sure how to deal with this error and would appreciate any help anyone can give. Thanks.

Comment: The command is correct are you sure you're running it from the correct directory? 
That error seems as if you're either in the wrong directory or you've got a corrupted zip file.

Comment: If you find the reason you're going wrong please post it below so others can find it to.

Comment: In command line I'm running it from the directory I put it in when i downloaded it. How would I know if I had a corrupted zip file?

Comment: Are you sure it's called stanford-corenlp-YYYY-MM-DD.jar? I would think they'd give the year-month-date of the build.

Comment: @hd1 LOL Yeah.. I'm assuming you replaced YYYY-MM-DD with the year month and date of your build. 

There's no real way to know if the ZIP file is corrupted. The only way is to re-download and see if it was messed up in the first place.

Comment: Can never be too sure, but I doubt the jar itself is corrupted

Comment: I did put in the actual dates so i don't think it's that.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using Windows? Have you checked the line below that reads

"For Windows, the colons (:) separating the jar files need to be semi-colons (;)."

Using the example, as is, will give you that error.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install Java 1.8 to be able to run this command.

Running the following commands will install Java 1.8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

This is taken directly from http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/; for more information you can use that page.

Comment: This answer was spot on for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, jar files in Stanford CoreNLP folder are named on versions such as Stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar in case of 2014-08-27 build. Either rename the file names as Stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar in command or rename the files in folder such as Stanford-corenlp-YYYY-MM-DD.jar.